# Twitter API post statuses/filter with Twitter OAuth Class

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I keep getting error code 34 (Sorry, this page does not exist) when attempting to make a post request to the statuses/filter method with the abraham twitteroauth class (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).  Following authentication (that's working fine) my request is simple:

`$filter = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/filter',array('track' => 'seo'));`

I have other calls working but even when I isolate this on a separate instance of the site, I'm only receiving the "Sorry, that page does not exist" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TwitterOAuth does not currently support the Streaming APIs. You can try the method that @JohnC suggests but I don't know if it will actually work.

[Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose/) is the PHP library I recommend for use with the Streaming APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The [`statuses/filter`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/filter) call uses a different URL to many of the other API calls - using stream.twitter.com instead of api.twitter.com. The library you are using appears to be hardcoded to only use api.twitter.com, so this could be the source of your problem. You can either change the URL for that call:

```php
$twitteroauth->host = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/";
$filter = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/filter',array('track' => 'seo'));
```

Or if you use the full URL it will override the default (probably the best way if you make multiple calls to the `$twitteroauth` class):

```
$filter = $twitteroauth->post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',array('track' => 'seo'));
```

Comment: This method doesn't work. I tried it and it gives NULL. That's true even if you use 1.1 instead of 1.